# unable to pull images in kubernetes from private registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes

i have setup a private registry in docker accessible thru a domain “makdom.ddns.net”, i can login push and pull images locally, no problem even from slave kubes node i can do this thing,

but when i write a kubes deployment file, it is unable to pull images from the private registry and fails.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ssh-deployment
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: helloworld
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ssh-demo
        image: makdom.ddns.net/my-ubuntu
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - name: nodejs-port
          containerPort: 22
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: myregistrykey
```

secrets:

```
DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER="https://makdom.ddns.net/v1/"
DOCKER_USER="user"
DOCKER_PASSWORD="password"
DOCKER_EMAIL="email@example.com" 

kubectl create secret docker-registry myregistrykey \
  --docker-server=$DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER \
  --docker-username=$DOCKER_USER \
  --docker-password=$DOCKER_PASSWORD \
  --docker-email=$DOCKER_EMAIL
```

error:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age               From                  Message
  ----     ------                 ----              ----                  -------
  Normal   Scheduled              1m                default-scheduler     Successfully assigned ssh-deployment-7b7c7bf977-m6stk to kubes-slave
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  1m                kubelet, kubes-slave  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-mx7qq"
  Normal   Pulled                 1m (x3 over 1m)   kubelet, kubes-slave  Container image "makdom.ddns.net/my-ubuntu" already present on machine
  Normal   Created                1m (x3 over 1m)   kubelet, kubes-slave  Created container
  Normal   Started                1m (x3 over 1m)   kubelet, kubes-slave  Started container
  Normal   Pulling                34s (x2 over 1m)  kubelet, kubes-slave  pulling image "makdom.ddns.net/my-ubuntu"
  Warning  Failed                 34s (x2 over 1m)  kubelet, kubes-slave  Failed to pull image "makdom.ddns.net/my-ubuntu": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error: image my-ubuntu:latest not found
  Warning  Failed                 34s (x2 over 1m)  kubelet, kubes-slave  Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  BackOff                19s (x6 over 1m)  kubelet, kubes-slave  Back-off restarting failed container
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known issue https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/57427, resolved in master in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/57463

Targeted fix for 1.9.1 in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/57472

Workarounds until then:

If you have a .dockerconfigjson for your private registry already, you can manually specify the type and data key:

```
kubectl create secret generic my-secret-name \
  --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson \
  --from-file .dockerconfigjson=/path/to/.dockerconfigjson
```

If you don't have a .dockerconfigjson file already, you can fix up the secret produced by `kubectl create secret docker-registry` manually:

1. add `--dry-run -o yaml > secret.yaml`
2. change the type from `kubernetes.io/dockercfg` to `kubernetes.io/dockercfgjson`
3. change the data key from `.dockercfg` to `.dockercfgjson`
4. create the modified secret with `kubectl create -f secret.yaml`

Comment: ok how can  i fix this, as im a little lost!